# filter data on a filtered datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void txtSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)

        {
            DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Description LIKE '%{0}%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%{0}%' OR ManufacturerItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%' OR ItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
                dataGridView.DataSource = dv;                   
                dataGridView.Update();
                dataGridView.Refresh();
        }

    }
```

first i connect to my sql database showing all records. then i run this code. works great when i enter something on text box. but further more i want to narrow down the filtered result by adding extra textbox. using the second textbox i want to filter my filtered data from the first textbox.

```
private void Descrip_txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dt = dv.ToTable();

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {       
         dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Description LIKE '%{0}%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%{0}%' OR ManufacturerItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%' OR ItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", Descrip_txtbox.Text);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dv
```

}

i want to take filtered data from txtsearch textbox the first search and filter again with the next text box and so on.

Can someone help me out?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an AND filter, it would look like this:

```
DataView dv = ((DataView)dataGridView.DataSource);  

var secondFilter = string.Format("Description LIKE '%{0}%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%{0}%' OR ManufacturerItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%' OR ItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", Descrip_txtbox.Text);

if ( dv.RowFilter == null || dv.RowFilter.Length == 0 )
    dv.RowFilter = secondFilter;
else
    dv.RowFilter = "(" + dv.RowFilter & ") AND " + secondFilter;

dataGridView.DataSource = dv;
```

And parenthesis and the AND are required because you want to further refine the filters, otherwise adding an OR might lead to the inclusion of more records.

Comment: how to display the filtered record to the datagrid?? and how i should use the same code to filter with the third text box?

Comment: the grid is already bound to the data view...so changing the filter will change the data grid

Comment: i replaced the code lines you gave me in my Descrip_txtbox_KeyDown.. but for some reason it deoesnt filter out the data on the grid.

Comment: i read you might have to reassign the data source after that - dataGridView.DataSource = dv;

Comment: Thanks you for helping me out. it works great until here but as soon as i use the same code for the third textbox. it eliminates the second filter and gets combined with the first one. advice?

Comment: to get the view, use DataView dv = ((DataView)dataGridView.DataSource);  you should be using the data view from the grid, not recreating one...that's another reason your filter will be wiped out

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are assigning new `value` to `dv.RowFilter` which will clear out previous filter.

You can just concatenate with it the new filter with `AND` like:

```
dv.RowFilter += " AND " + string.Format("Description LIKE '%{0}%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%{0}%' OR ManufacturerItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%' OR ItemNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", Descrip_txtbox.Text);
```

Comment: thank you Ehsan, i used your code too. but  this work only upto 2 textboxes values. as soon as i try with the third one. it just eliminates the second filter. could you please help